# d3js - animate tree structure

Tags: javascript, tree, d3.js, transition

I'm using the radial tree example from d3.js ([tree-radial.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/tree/tree-radial.js)) and when you click on a node it should move to the center (set it as the new root). I want to get a smooth transition from one tree structure to another but I can't get it to work at all. The click is recognized but I'm not sure how to transition the nodes. Can somebody explain me the steps to get this work or link a short example where this is done?

Comment: Possible solution: to find the displacement of clicked node; then select all nodes, and apply the transition: subtracting the displacement from each node.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps, but you can have a look at this: http://bl.ocks.org/1249394. The clicked node doesn't move to the center in this example, but in essence you will still need to make some similar transitions, just that you will have to adjust the position of the node to be in the center (slightly different coordinates for the transform).